# Can I efficiently return an object by value in Rust?

Tags: optimization, rust, return-value-optimization

I would like to initialize a large object with a function. Currently I have:

```
fn initialize(mydata: &mut Vec<Vec<MyStruct>>) { /* ... */ }
```

I would prefer to have:

```
fn initialize() -> Vec<Vec<MyStruct>> { /* ... */ }
```

I've heard that C++ often implements return value optimization (RVO), if you are lucky and have a good compiler. Can we disable copying here and have it returned by a hidden pointer that is passed into the function? Is RVO part of the language or an optional optimization?

Comment: [This discussion](http://discuss.rust-lang.org/t/implementation-details/948/5) suggests that RVO triggers for anything larger than a pointer. But there's also [this open issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/18363) regarding NRVO. So I guess it depends on exactly how you implement `initialize`.

Answer (score 23):

Yes, by all means, you should write

```
fn initialize() -> Vec<Vec<MyStruct>> { ... }
```

(By the way, a `Vec` is not that large - it's only 3 pointer-sized integers)

Rust has RVO, and this [is advertised in guides](https://web.archive.org/web/20141225073722/https://doc.rust-lang.org/guide-pointers.html#returning-pointers). You can see it yourself with this code:

```
#[inline(never)]
fn initialize() -> Vec<i32> {
    Vec::new()
}

fn main() {
    let v = initialize();
}
```

If you compile this program in release mode [on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=994e26e3f0a38e52a6473b9bf8656cc1&version=stable&mode=release), outputting assembly, among everything else you will see this:

```
playground::initialize:
    movq    $4, (%rdi)
    xorps   %xmm0, %xmm0
    movups  %xmm0, 8(%rdi)
    retq
```

`Vec::new()` was inlined, but you can see the idea - the address for the fresh `Vec` instance is passed into the function in `%rdi`, and the function stores `Vec` fields directly into this memory, avoiding unnecessary copying through the stack. This is how it is called:

```
playground::main:
    subq    $24, %rsp
    movq    %rsp, %rdi
    callq   playground::initialize
```

You can see that eventually the `Vec` instance will be put directly into the stack memory.

Comment: Probably, but I find LLVM IR read much harder than the assembly for some reason :(

Comment: For this we just need the signature: `define internal fastcc void @initialize(%"struct.collections::vec::Vec<[i32]>[#3]"* noalias nocapture sret dereferenceable(24)) unnamed_addr #0`. LLVM IR is similar C for declarations, so that function returns `void` and takes a pointer (`*`) to a `struct.collections::vec::Vec<[i32]>`. (I used `#[no_mangle]` to make it clearer.)

Comment: That might show passing a pointer, but if you look at the end of the LLVM IR, you might see a memcpy into that block of memory or similar. I have a piece of code I wrote that allocates a 256 int array to return and if you look at the bottom of the IR, you see the copy from one object to another. Looking at the generated ASM (both beta and nightly on play.r-l.org), you see the call to mempcy@PLT at the bottom of the function call. http://is.gd/u9GVx6