# Why does Iterator::next return an Option instead of just an item?

Tags: iterator, rust

It seems to me that whether an option is the right type to return should be up to the implementor.

I notice that it goes away when I try to filter or using other collection methods on the items. Is this simply a replacement for `has_next`? Won't it have potential performance/memory implications?

Comment: What should `[].iter().next()` do?

Comment: "and won't it have potential performance/memory-implications?" no more that any < size or != NULL or similar.

Comment: @trentcl I guess it's a priority in Rust to avoid panic on an exhausted iterators. Other languages use has_next and then panics on next. It just feels like a big overhead on a quite low-level construct.

Comment: @Stargateur If you create an iterator over bytes (u8) you will have created as many Somes has you have bytes.

Comment: @thoredge no, it's an additional 8 bytes at maximum (and often even 0) for **one** entry at a time; moving to the next `Item` drops the previous one.

Comment: [What is the overhead of Rust's Option type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16504643/155423)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because it needs *some* way to communicate to the caller that there's nothing left to output.

```
fn main() {
    let mut it = vec![1, 2, 3].into_iter();
    assert_eq!(it.next(), Some(1));
    assert_eq!(it.next(), Some(2));
    assert_eq!(it.next(), Some(3));
    assert_eq!(it.next(), None); // End of iterator.
}
```

As for a hypothetical `has_next`, that can complicate some iterator designs because it requires the iterator to *know* whether there is another element.  This might require the iterator to compute the next element, then store it somewhere.  It's also possible to forget to call `has_next`, or call it but ignore the result.

With `next` returning an `Option`, none of this is an issue; an iterator can compute the next item and return it whilst making it impossible for a caller to forget to ensure the returned value actually has something in it.

One thing this does *not* let you do is "peek" at the iterator to see if there's something more and then change logic based on that answer, *without* actually consuming the next item.  However, that's what the `peekable` combinator is for, which gives you what amounts to a traditional `has_next`: `peek().is_some()`.

On your concerns about performance: I've never seen anything to suggest there is any penalty.  Anything using an iterator correctly *has* to check to see if it's reached the end.  As for space, a Rust iterator doesn't need to cache the next item, so they're likely to be the same size or smaller than an iterator for a language that uses `has_next`.

Finally, as noted in comments, `Option` is not heap allocated.  A `None` is equivalent to a `false` followed by some uninitialised space (since there's nothing in it), and a `Some(v)` is equivalent to a `true` followed by `v`.

Comment: My point is it feels like a very expensive way to do it. If you create an iterator over bytes (u8) you will have created as many Somes has you have bytes.

Comment: @thoredge: And if you use `has_next`, you will have created as many `bool`s as you have bytes.

Comment: @thoredge: Wait a second, are you under the impression that `Option` is heap allocated?

Comment: More like a conditioned intuition ;-). Yes that is probably what was nagging me. The Some with the i32 (for example) will reside on the stack until picked up by the caller; is that right?

Comment: @thoredge An `Option<i32>` is essentially (as far as layout is concerned) a `(bool, i32)` tuple. The `bool` and `i32` will in probably be returned in registers, but things larger than `i32` might be reserved on the caller's stack and written directly there; [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835375/can-i-efficiently-return-object-by-value-in-rust) has more info.

Comment: @thoredge: Also, if the `T` in `Option<T>` is a type that won't ever have an all-zeroes bit pattern, [the compiler can optimize the tag out entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46557608/what-is-the-null-pointer-optimization-in-rust). For example, `Option<&Foo>` is the same size as `&Foo`.